# Finding missing element in two array for javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, comparison

I have a problem in Node.js.. My problem is two arrays comparing. For example;

My original array is;

```
var a = ["1","2","3","4","5"];
```

and the other array is;

```
var b = ["3","1","4","6","8","7"];
```

so, result message what I want is:
 "2 and 5 is missing the original array.."

So how can I get this message after comparison of two arrays?

Comment: Using jQuery you can do like `var diff = $(a).not(b).get();`

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter array elements.

```js
var a = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var b = ["3", "1", "4", "6", "8", "7"];

console.log(
  a.filter(function(v) {
    return !b.includes(v);
  })
)

// or for older browser

console.log(
  a.filter(function(v) {
    return b.indexOf(v) == -1;
  })
)
```