# How to use filter to compare to arrays to find missing object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use arr.filter() to find the missing element between two arrays, this has been answered plenty of times and i've seen threads like this one [Finding missing element in two array for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801729/finding-missing-element-in-two-array-for-javascript) that explain it actually very well. For some reason thought, i cant seem to get this to work.

This is my code

```
var x = [{Number:1},{Number:2},{Number:3}]
var y = [{Number:1},{Number:2}]

function getDifference(x,y){

    x.filter(function(object,index,arr){
        console.log(object,index,arr)
        if(!y.includes(object)){
            // print object
            console.log(object) // <-- Prints all 3, should just print the missing one.
        }
    })

}

getDifference(x,y)
```

Basically, it just needs to print out the missing object. Which in this case, is `{Number:3}`
Instead, it prints every object.

I've tried with the code in the thread that i linked above, and still was having trouble. Not sure what i'm not understanding with it.

Comment: `{Number: 1} === {Number: 1}` => `false`

Comment: It is because those are different objects, for ex: `{} !== {}` is `true`.

Comment: These are different objects (i.e. not equal). You have to compare them by their properties.